# Symfony2 moneyfield no negative values

Tags: symfony

In have a form in symfony2 with a fieldtype money but i don't know how to set a validator to accept only positiv values

```
$builder->add(
        'costs',
        'money',
        array('label' => 'modell.table.costs')
    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a version of symfony >=2.3 you can use GreaterThanOrEqual Validator:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/GreaterThanOrEqual.html

Otherwise you can configure the Range Validator:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Range.html

Hope this help

Comment: this helped me thanks but one thing, do you know how to set the validator for a fieldtype in this example Money ??

Comment: you can add a **constraint** in the third arguments of the **add** method with an arrays of validator object as described as this link: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#adding-validation